# Why is a javascript hash object not evaluated during argument passing?

Tags: javascript

for a simple function such as

```
function foo(hash)
 {
   for(var k in hash){
    if (h.hasOwnProperty(k)){
        console.log('Key is: ' + k + ', value is: ' + h[k]);
    }
   }
}
```

if you passing an argument like

```
var m = new Object();
m['one'] = 1;
foo(m);
```

you will see the result on your console, but if you pass an argument like

```
foo(({} ['one'] =1));
```

or

```
foo((new Object()['one'] = 1));
```

it will no go through the for-loop,
the expression

```
(new Object()['one'] = 1) == m
```

returns false while,

```
(new Object()['one'] = 1) == ({} ['one'] = 1)
```

return true

any ideas why not? Thanks!!!

Comment: I don't think it's the problem, but were you aware that == does type coercion? Use === instead.

Answer (score 2):

This expression is an assignment so it will returned the assigned value, not a new object with a field called `one` with the value `1`.

```
console.log(new Object()['one'] = 1); // outputs '1'

var m = new Object();
m.one = 1;
console.log(m); //outputs the object with its set property

//Here you are comparing the value 1, returned by the expression in parentheses, to an object
(new Object()['one'] = 1) == m
```

Answer (score 2):

The property assignment evaluates to the assigned value, not the object to which the property was assigned. From [the ECMAScript (ECMA-262) spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm):

> #### 11.13.1 Simple Assignment (`=`)
>
> The production `AssignmentExpression : LeftHandSideExpression =
>   AssignmentExpression` is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Let `lref` be the result of evaluating `LeftHandSideExpression`.
> 2. Let `rref` be the result of evaluating `AssignmentExpression`.
> 3. Let `rval` be `GetValue(rref)`.
> 4. Throw a `SyntaxError` exception if the following conditions are all true:
>
>    - `Type(lref)` is Reference is `true`
>    - `IsStrictReference(lref)` is `true`
>    - `Type(GetBase(lref))` is Environment Record
>    - `GetReferencedName(lref)` is either "eval" or "arguments"
> 5. Call `PutValue(lref, rval)`.
> 6. **Return `rval`.**

[(emphasis added)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fUCE.png)